# Debug JavaScript code in vs.net 2010

Tags: javascript, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I have a `win-form` Application with a web browser control.

i use a `JavaScript` code in this web browser.but some times my JavaScript code return `error`

I want to know is it possible to debug JavaScript code in vs.net 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug Javascript running in an ASP.Net application (WebForms or MVC), but not in your Win Forms application.  If you have the code for the site that the browser control is running then you can start a session of that in VS 2010 and debug away.

Comment: exactly i know this,i just want to know it's possible in win form or no.thnx

Comment: If you can point the browser control at a debug session of the target site it *might* work.